# No Bluetooth adaptors found

Tags: linux, debian, debian-wheezy

I have problems enabling my bluetooth in my newly bought Lenovo Ideapad B490 Series. I have searched the internet for solutions. It isn't even listing in `lspci` or `lsusb`. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Please let me know if I have to post the output of any commands.

TIA
Mobin

Comment: Can you not download and manually install the drivers from their site below? http://support.lenovo.com/en_GB/downloads/detail.page?DocID=DS032617 Also do you get any errors in Device Manager?

Comment: thanks for your valuable suggestion @BenLavender. Will check the website and let you know. Also where can I find device manager in debian?